# How to jump from one intent to another in LuisActionDialog passing context

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm developing a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework, LUIS and [LUISActionBinding](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding).

In my LUIS app I have 3 main intents: **BuyX**, **FindA** and **FindB**. The main goal of the bot is to help users to buy X, but they might want to first search for A or B with some filters first, or just go directly to buy X.

I set up the Actions for each intent with the required and optional fields, everything works great and I'm able to receive objects returned by the actions my intent handlers.

In the FindA handler I help the user selecting one A and in the FindB handler I help the user selecting one B. In BuyX I need info from A and B to proceed. But if users did the FindA or FindB dialog I want to reuse stuff I got there.

My question is how can I trigger intent BuyX from intent FindA, so that the code reaches my BuyXAction class *with* some properties already assigned based on what I was able to acquire from the FindA action+intent.

This way the user wouldn't have to type anything saying he wants to buy X nor repeat stuff he already did/select during the FindA dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the concept of SubActions might help you here. Take a look at this [documentation topic](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding#scenario-3--trigger-a-contextual-action-with-no-previous-context-ie-from-scratch) to find more about how it work and some code highlights.

> **Trigger a Contextual Action with no previous Context (ie. from
>   scratch)**
>
> The user can provide an input that will trigger a contextual action
>   (with no current context). The framework supports this scenario by
>   providing a way to instantiate the contexts chain for it (ie. the
>   chain of parent actions that provides will provide the whole context),
>   and finally executes the request.

Comment: That concept was one of the reasons why I chose to use ActionBinding. My idea was to create sub actions for BuyX, like BuyX_ChangeY, BuyX_ChangeZ, etc. But those Y and Z are not necessarily be my A and B. Are you suggesting I should make FindA and FindB extend BaseLuisContextualAction<BuyX>?

Comment: Yes, I would try that.

Comment: In my FindActions i'm getting data from services and filtering based on user inputs and returning a list of objects back to the corresponding intent handlers. There I use the list to show cards to the user with options to get more info or select one. With this approach I'd have to move all the code in the FindA/B intent handlers to the BuyX intent handler right?

Comment: Also, what happens to the objects returned by contextual actions? Are they simply discarded if they are not strings? My code is reaching [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding/Microsoft.Cognitive.LUIS.ActionBinding/Bot/LuisActionDialog.cs#L379), but I need to return a list of objects. Maybe I need to create new properties in the BuyX action for these lists?

Comment: Yes, objects returned by contextual actions are discarded if they are not strings. I believe you should tweak the parent context on those subactions.