# How do i trigger LUIS in any dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

For example, i had a LuisDialog that contains all my intent and it will direct to certain iDialog base on the intent. However, when i'm in the iDialog and i wanted to type something that will trigger the other LUIS intent and go to the other dialog. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sample code that you can show?

If I understood you correctly, you want to move from Intent A to Intent B?

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331800/how-to-jump-from-one-intent-to-another-in-luisactiondialog-passing-context)? It seems very similar to what you are asking.